# Update table's Column From other's Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I use SQL Server and have 2 tables in the same database.

Tables are `a` and `b`

```
  Table a              and     Table b

  ID  Group   Wname            ID    Wname      Group
   1  Sword                     1 Magic Sword   Sword
   2  Sword                     2 Nature Sword  Sword
   3  Sword                     
   4  Sword
```

I would like take Table b's `Wname` column values and appy them to Table a's `Wname` column

The result should be:

```
  Table a

  ID Group   Wname
   1 Sword   Magic Sword
   2 Sword   Nature Sword
   3 Sword   Magic Sword
   4 Sword   Nature Sword
```

I try some functions, but result is not what I need.

I need some different function

I tried:

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET Wname = b.Wname 
FROM Tableb b 
WHERE Group = b.Group
```

The result is:

```
 Table a

  ID Group   Wname
   1 Sword   Magic Sword
   2 Sword   Magic Sword
   3 Sword   Magic Sword
   4 Sword   Magic Sword
```

Attempt #2

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET Wname = (SELECT Wname FROM Tableb) 
WHERE Group = b.Group
```

Result error is :

> the Values != 1, Can't Update.......

Comment: What is the link between two tables,?

Comment: Show us what you tried, even if it didn't work. Maybe you are almost there already.

Comment: I add what I try Functions imformation in Questions, I'm not alomst there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, This will work for you

```
Update  a
Set     a.Wname  = b.Wname
From    [Table a] a
Join    [Table b] b On (a.Id %2) = (b.Id % 2)
```